# Foreach multidimensional array display values

Tags: php, mysql

Within a BPM application, I'm trying to loop through an associative array of associative arrays and return only the values (APP_UIDs) using a foreach loop. However, I'm only able to display the very last generated value and not all the values.

Here is my code:

```
$currentUser = @@USER_LOGGED;
//Copy Notes to Subprocess
$caseId = @@APPLICATION; //Case UID
$subcases = executeQuery("SELECT APP_UID FROM SUB_APPLICATION WHERE APP_PARENT='$caseId'");
if (is_array($subcases) and count($subcases) > 0) { 
  foreach($subcases as $subcase)
  $subCaseId = $subcase["APP_UID"] . ", ";

//Update the Sent By status
executeQuery("UPDATE APP_CACHE_VIEW SET PREVIOUS_USR_UID = '$currentUser' WHERE APP_UID IN ('$subCaseId')");
}
```

The executeQuery function should generate a SQL statement of something like below but it is not. Example:

```
UPDATE APP_CACHE_VIEW SET PREVIOUS_USR_UID = '54454572356235' WHERE APP_UID IN      
('336545547', '436545534', '736545125')
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The others have given you the correct answer. However I just want to say that in these cases of building IN statements, I prefer to create an array with the values to be used, then create the comma separated string using implode(',', $array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing concatenation here:

Initialize variable like below on top of loop:

```
$subCaseId = '';
```

and use concatenation operator `.=` as below:

```
$subCaseId .= $subcase["APP_UID"] . ", ";
```

Ideally, you should also remove last command and space from variable `$subCaseId`

also you need to remove single quote around this variable  for IN query.

See complete solution as below:

```
$currentUser = @@USER_LOGGED;
//Copy Notes to Subprocess
$caseId = @@APPLICATION; //Case UID
$subcases = executeQuery("SELECT APP_UID FROM SUB_APPLICATION WHERE APP_PARENT='$caseId'");
if (is_array($subcases) and count($subcases) > 0) { 
    $subCaseId = '';
      foreach($subcases as $subcase)
          $subCaseId = $subcase["APP_UID"] . ", ";
    //To remove last comma and space
    $subCaseId = substr($subCaseId,0,-2);

//Update the Sent By status
executeQuery("UPDATE APP_CACHE_VIEW SET PREVIOUS_USR_UID = '$currentUser' WHERE APP_UID IN ($subCaseId)");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this.

```
    $currentUser = @@USER_LOGGED;
    //Copy Notes to Subprocess
    $caseId = @@APPLICATION; //Case UID
    $subcases = executeQuery("SELECT APP_UID FROM SUB_APPLICATION WHERE APP_PARENT='$caseId'");
    if (is_array($subcases) and count($subcases) > 0) { 
      $subCaseId = '';
      foreach($subcases as $subcase)
      $subCaseId .= $subcase["APP_UID"] . ", ";

    //Update the Sent By status
    executeQuery("UPDATE APP_CACHE_VIEW SET PREVIOUS_USR_UID = '$currentUser' WHERE APP_UID IN ('$subCaseId')");
    }
```

Also don't forget to 'reinitialize the string' by doing `$subCaseId = '';` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 foreach($subcases as $subcase)
  $subCaseId = $subcase["APP_UID"] . ", ";
```

to :

```
  $subCaseId = '';
  foreach($subcases as $subcase)
  $subCaseId .= $subcase["APP_UID"] . ", ";
```

Note the concatenation `.=`